# Discord.py program to convert a message to string

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is my first question here. I am coding a python discord bot where i want to convert the message of any user to string, like if anyone types,

> Hello there!

then the bot would convert the message to String.

I have tried on my own, (by taking jelp from the internet),. I wrote,

```
if message.content=='test':
   text=message.content
   await message.channel.send(text)
```

but whenever i type 'test', it sends as

> Mr. Incognito test

Here `Mr. Incognito` is my name. I don't want my name to get displayed ere. I just want the `test` word to be displayed.

Can anyone solve my question?

Comment: Is this an `on_message` event? I do not know where the problem is, as your code does not display the name. See my [output](https://imgur.com/a/ZbxPG71)

Comment: Yes @Dominik this in an `on_message` event.

Comment: So what is the problem here? Can you post a screenshot of the output?

Answer (score -1):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@client.command()
async def equal(ctx, message):
  await ctx.send(message)

client.run('PUTYOURTOKENHERE')
```